# Pass a value from inside the Azure ADF pipeline to a PowerShell where the pipeline invoked

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I want to do some steps in my PowerShell based on a value from an Azure ADF(Azure Data Factory) pipeline. How can I pass a value from an ADF pipeline to the PowerShell, where I invoked this ADF Pipeline?  So that, I can do the appropriate steps in the PowerShell based on a value I received from ADF pipeline.

NOTE: I am not looking for the run-status of the pipeline (success, failure etc), but I am looking for some variable-value that we get inside a pipeline - say, a flag-value we obtained from a table using a Lookup activity etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share a code sample and perhaps with a bit more context it'll be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: You can try to get the output of an activity run in powershell. There you can find some result of the activity.

Comment: minor edits/modification.

Comment: Yes Yusheng, I see this option now. I think I have to do the parse it and get what I want to from it.  Ok let me see.

Comment: If you adopt my answer, you could mark it. That's really helpful for others' reference on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

KPK, the requirements you're talking about definitely can be fulfilled though I do not know where does your Powershell scripts run.

You could write your Powershell scripts in [HTTP Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook),please refer to this [doc](https://www.brianbunke.com/blog/2018/02/27/powershell-in-azure-functions/). Then you could get the output of the pipeline in Powershell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/invoke-azurermdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azurermps-4.4.1#outputs.

Then pass the value you want to HTTP Trigger Azure Function as parameters.

Comment: @KPK That's great! Please mark my answer for others' reference on the forum. Thanks a lot.